# Referencing the anchor tag that was clicked: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I keep getting

> "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

, indicating to me that the `$(this)` in the below code is undefined. Why is that?

**HTML:**

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td><a class='edit-link' id='jobid-3'>Motion Designer</a></td>
      <td>2015-07-21 11:06:57</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><a class='edit-link' id='jobid-2'>Web Developer</a></td>
      <td>2015-07-21 09:53:36</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><a class='edit-link' id='jobid-1'>Creative Team Manager</a></td>
      <td>2015-07-21 09:41:20</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.edit-link').click(function() {
    {
        var thisJobId = jQuery(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
        console.log("thisJobId = " + thisJobId); // test
    });
<script>
```

Comment: You are not handling the event

Comment: @kmsdev Sorry, type-o

Comment: Is your code at the bottom of the page? If not, you may be attempting to attach the the link before it exists in the DOM.

Comment: You have an extra `{` now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event binding in your code example.

So use like this

```
jQuery('.edit-link').on("click", function() {
    var thisJobId = jQuery(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    console.log("thisJobId = " + thisJobId); // test
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

Attach a click handler to the class:

```js
$('.edit-link').click(function(){
   
        var thisJobId = jQuery(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
        console.log("thisJobId = " + thisJobId); // test
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td><a class='edit-link' id='jobid-3'>Motion Designer</a></td>
      <td>2015-07-21 11:06:57</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><a class='edit-link' id='jobid-2'>Web Developer</a></td>
      <td>2015-07-21 09:53:36</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><a class='edit-link' id='jobid-1'>Creative Team Manager</a></td>
      <td>2015-07-21 09:41:20</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `click` event property:

```
jQuery('.edit-link').click(function(){
    var thisJobId = jQuery(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    console.log("thisJobId = " + thisJobId); // test
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify javascript:

```
$('.edit-link').click(function(event) {
    var thisJobId = event.target.id.split('-')[1];
    console.log("thisJobId = " + thisJobId);
});
```

Above function executes upon clicking on element. Inside event object there is target property which contains DOM element that was clicked. I'm retrieving it's id and returning only the part you need.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnx0r93z/)